# Composer with PHP 7.0.3 and Apache 2.4.18 on Windows 10

Tags: php, apache, openssl, composer-php

Just installed Apache and PHP. Now I'm trying to install Composer on my PC, but it keeps giving me an error during installation:

> The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure 
>       HTTPS transfers are impossible. 
>       If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl

And yep, OpenSSL is enabled in my `php.ini`

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

So... what's next?

**EDITED**

When running phpinfo(), openssl line shows:

```
OpenSSL support :   disabled (install ext/openssl)
```

But the dll(php_openssl.dll) is in the ext folder. Is there another way to install/enable openssl?

**"SOLUTION"**

So composer is up and running. I`m just not really shure why, but here what I`ve done:

- I had php 7.0.3 ThreadSafe, and changed for the non safe(only renamed the php7 folder and puted the other one with the same name);
- Enabled openssl in php.ini, restarted apache;
- Apache didn`t started cause php7apache2_4.dll didn`t existed, so I copy the one from the treadsafe;
- Apache still didn`t started, so I just renamed back the treadsafe folder as php7 and runned one last time phpinfo();

And there it was:

```
OpenSSL support:enabled
OpenSSL Library Version:OpenSSL 1.0.2e 3 Dec 2015
OpenSSL Header Version:OpenSSL 1.0.2f 28 Jan 2016
Openssl default config:c:/openssl-1.0.2e-win64/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

Sorry that I`m don't really know whats changed, so the question remains open, but theres something to try on, somehow worked for me.

Comment: Is it possible that you have another PHP installation that composer autodetected? Check you PATH variables. Did you restarted apache after enabling```php_openssl.dll```?

Comment: Try running `php --ini` to find out which ini file was used.

Comment: No other version installed, just got windows10 with a clean install. When installing composer I choose the path of php.exe, so it's the right file. And phpinfo() in openssl line: OpenSSL support  disabled (install ext/openssl).. and yep, apache restarted, even rebooted the machine